# Unable to open .jar files with Java

Tags: java, jdk, openjdk

I'm using Lubuntu and trying to open a file named Minecraft.jar, but all the solutions that work for other people aren't working for me. I have these versions of Java installed:

> openjdk version "9-internal"OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

When I try to right click it and open with OpenJDK Java 8 runtime nothing happens and whenever I try the java -jar command in terminal this is all I get:

```
mitochondria@Mina:~$ java -jar /home/mitochondria/Desktop/Minecraft.jar
```

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fc01b121009, pid=20039, tid=20040
>
> JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (9.0) (build
>   9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)  Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit
>   Server VM (9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode,
>   tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)  Problematic frame:  C 
>   [libjava.so+0x1d009]  JNU_GetEnv+0x19
>
> Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be
>   processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %P" (or dumping to
>   /home/mitochondria/core.20039)
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   /home/mitochondria/hs_err_pid20039.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp  The crash happened
>   outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.  See problematic
>   frame for where to report the bug.
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You seem to be using a development version of java : Java 9 has not been released yet.

So, first of all, you should remove this version of java, and install the default one :

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-*
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Depending on your version of Ubuntu, it should be a version 7 or 8.
If you're on a development version of Ubuntu, you might need to choose version 8 :
    sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre

Then you should be able to run Minecraft.

By the way, the simplest method to install it is to use the PPA instead of trying to run the .jar by hand :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Comment: Not only did this solve the issue, but you went above and beyond in showing how to more easily achieve the end result requested.  

Excellent first post, IMHO.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to figure this out for days! The instructions were clear, and effective!

Comment: A native Linux launcher for Minecraft has been released and can be downloaded as Deb file. If you are still using 16.04 you will have to build libicu from source